# Django: Reverse for ‘topic_posts’ with arguments ‘(3, ”)’ not found

Tags: django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

The reverse of '‘topic_posts’ works fine in other places. But it doesn’t work here.
HTML file

```
                 <td class="align-middle">
                    {% with post=board.get_last_post %}
                    <small>
                        <a href="{% url 'topic_posts' board.id post.topic.id %}">
                            By {{ post.created_by.username }} at {{ post.created_at }}
                            id - {{ board.id }} {{ post.topic.id }}
                        </a>
                    </small>
                    {% endwith %}
                </td>
```

url setting

```
path('boards/<int:board_id>/topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic_posts, name='topic_posts'),
```

```
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, board_id=board_id, id=topic_id)
    return render(request, 'topic_posts.html', {'topic': topic})
```

When I changed the `board.id` and `post.topic.id` to integer value , for exmaple 1 and 24, the web would render. I commented `<a href="{% url 'topic_posts' board.id post.topic.id %}">` and added `{{ board.id }} {{ post.topic.id }}` to see if there is an error with the query, turned out there is no problem, it would render 1, 24 on the webpage. Then I tried `<a href="{% url 'topic_posts' board.id 24 %}">` It worked fine, but `<a href="{% url 'topic_posts' board.id post.topic.id %}">` still won’t work.

```
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_posts_count(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(topic__board=self).count()

    def get_last_post(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(topic__board=self).order_by('-created_at').first()
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is the template code inside a for loop? It seems when `board.id=3` then `post.topic.id` is empty. Which is what the error `(3, '')` is telling you. Can you share the code for `get_last_post`? It's likely this is not returning anything.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reading. I have edited the post.  ```{{ post.topic.id }}``` will give me 24 when i commented the  ```<a href="{% url 'topic_posts' board.id post.topic.id %}"></a>```

Comment: Is your template code you have shown inside a for loop? I don't think you are getting `24` for `{{ post.topic.id }}` when `board.id` is `3`. You can check this by printing `print(Post.objects.filter(topic__board_id=3).order_by('-created_at').first())` inside `get_last_post` before the return. This will likely be empty.

Comment: This ```id - {{ board.id }} {{ post.topic.id }}``` gives me  id - 1 24, which contradict the error ‘(3, ”)’ the error ```board.id ```gives 3 ?

Comment: Yes, it is inside a for loop

Comment: You get `1` and `24` fine for the first iteration of the for loop but when the `board.id` is equal to `3` (likely the third iteration), there is no latest post, which is why its empty and throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a loop in your template/HTML code. The reason it works for `1` and `24` is because this is the first iteration of the loop and your function `get_last_post` returns the latest post for a `board` with the `id` of `1`. But when the for loop finds a `board` with an `id` of `3`, no latest post exists and is returning `None` or empty. Which is why you are getting this error. The error is essentially saying, I can't find a URL with only a `board_id=3` and an empty `post_id`.

You can confirm this by printing:

```
print(Post.objects.filter(topic__board_id=3).order_by('-created_at').first())
```

or by checking your database for any posts on a board with an `id` of `3`.

You can resolve this by showing the link *only* if a board with a latest post exists like:

```
{% if post.topic.id %}
<a href="{% url 'topic_posts' board.id post.topic.id %}">
    By {{ post.created_by.username }} at {{ post.created_at }} id - {{ board.id }} {{ post.topic.id }}
</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your time! Yes, I didn't populate any data on board.id = 3. Now I see why it won't work. But How to avoid the problem when there is no data on board.id = 3

Comment: You just need to ensure your handling when this is empty, like I showed inside the HTML code with an `if` statement.

Comment: You are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{% url 'topic_posts' board.id post.topic.id %}">
```

Django can't understand **board** and **post** here.
try to send it through context along with the template during return render

try this:

```
return render(request, 'topic_posts.html', {'topic': topic, 'board': board, 'post': post})
```

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your answer. The problem is the for loop.  The HTML code I post is inside a for loop. I didn't  populate any data for board.id = 3, so post.topic.id gets empty.

Comment: thank you @WeiWong . Glad to know that your problem solved.